# how to run 2 different processes at the same time?

Tags: python, sockets, parallel-processing, queue

One process is receiving data from a socket and then putting it in a queue, and the other one is processing the queued data. How to make them both run at the same time?

This socket is serve_forever while the processing of data will only run if the queue is not empty.

Comment: Do you want 2 parallel processes or threads?

Comment: i want 2 parallel processes. i just need the 2nd process to be linear.

Comment: `multiprocessing` module

Answer (score 1):

i have it working. i don't know if this is THE ANSWER. but it's working, well, so far. maybe there are or there will be bugs (hopefully none). any suggestions for improvements is welcome.

```
import multiprocessing
import socket
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def handle(connection, address):
  try:
    while True:
      data = connection.recv(1024)
      if data == "":
        break
      else :
        print "RECEIVE DATA : " + str(data)
        xdata = data.strip()
        xdata = data.split(" ")
        for xd in xdata :
          print "PUT Task : " + str(xd)
          QueueTask.put((xd), block=True, timeout=5)
      connection.sendall(data)
  except:
    print "Problem handling request"
  finally:
    connection.close()

class Server(object):
  def __init__(self, hostname, port):
    self.hostname = hostname
    self.port = port

  def start(self):
    self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    self.socket.bind((self.hostname, self.port))
    self.socket.listen(1)
    while True:
      conn, address = self.socket.accept()
      process = multiprocessing.Process(target=handle, args=(conn, address))
      process.daemon = True
      process.start()

def f_Processor():
  time.sleep(10)
  print 'PROCESSOR Starting'
  while 1:
    try :
      job = QueueTask.get(True,1)
      print "GET Task : " + str(job)
      time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as err :
      pass
  print 'PROCESSOR Exiting'

if __name__ == "__main__":
  server = Server("localhost", 9999)
  QueueTask = Queue()
  try:
    p = multiprocessing.Process(name='Processing', target=f_Processor)
    p.start()
    server.start()
    p.join()
  except:
    print "Unexpected exception"
  finally:
    for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
      process.terminate()
      process.join()
  print "All done"
```

Answer (score 0):

Also it's depend, if you have a server or client application. If it is a server than you can use

```
    SocketServer.TCPServer.allow_reuse_address = True       

    self.server = TCPFactory( ( HOST, PORT ), TCPRequestHandler, params )                      

    # Start a thread with the server        
    self.server_thread = threading.Thread( target = self.server.serve_forever )


    self.server_thread.setDaemon( True )       
    self.server_thread.start()

class TCPFactory( SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer ):    


    def __init__( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass, params ):
        """
        """

        SocketServer.ThreadingTCPServer.__init__( self, server_address, RequestHandlerClass )
        self.patrams = params


class TCPRequestHandler( SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler ):

    def setup( self ):
       print self.server.params
       pass
    def handle( self ):
       pass
```

So if a client connected to the server it will start a new thread. The `setup` and
`handler` function will be called automatically. 
For the other thread you can use a timer, or an other thread

```
myt = Timer( 2, chackque, () )
myt.start()

def chackque():
   if not myq.empty():
   #Do what you want
```

or just start an other thread:

```
mythread = threading.Thread( target = chackque, args = ( myargs, ) )        
mythread.setDaemon( True )
mythread.start()

def chackque():
   while True:
       if not myq.empty():
       #Do what you want
```

Comment: yes, i have both the client and server applications. this receiving application is the server application, but i don't want this to create threads. i just want the 2nd process to be linear. like just one data will be processed at a time. the first process will just receive data from the client application. i looked into multiprocessing, but i can't seem to grasp how this works.